# The Scalar-to-Matrix Derivative of $\frac 1 2 \| V \sigma \left( Wx \right) - y \|_2^2$ w.r.t. $W$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus, matrix-analysis

I'd appreciate your help in explaining the steps of calculating [$\frac {\partial L} {\partial W}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix), where

$$
L := \frac  1 2 \| V \sigma \left( Wx \right) - y \|_2^2
$$

and $
x \in \mathbb{R}^{(d \times 1)}, 
W \in \mathbb{R}^{(k \times d)},
V \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times k)},
y \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times 1)}
$, for $\sigma \left( u \right) := \max \left( 0, u \right)$ element-wise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the scalar case, the derivative of the ReLu function
is the [Heaviside step function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function), i.e.
$$\frac{d\sigma(x)}{dx} = \theta(x) \quad\implies\quad d\sigma = \theta\,dx$$
When applied element-wise on a vector $(z)$ these functions produce vectors
$$\eqalign{
s &= \sigma(z) \quad\quad h &= \theta(z) \\
}$$
whose gradient can be calculated using the elementwise/Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
ds &= h\odot dz = H\,dz \quad\implies\quad
\frac{\partial s}{\partial z} &= H \\
}$$
where $\odot$ denotes the Hadamard product and $H={\rm Diag}(h)$

For your specific problem let $\,z = Wx,\;p=(Vs-y)\;$ and
$$\eqalign{
 L &= \tfrac 12\;p:p \\
dL &= p:dp \\
 &= p:V\,ds \\
 &= p:VH\,dW\,x \\
 &= HV^Tpx^T:dW \\
 &= {\rm Diag}\big(\theta(Wx)\big)\,V^T\big(V\sigma(Wx)-y\big)x^T:dW \\
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}
 &= {\rm Diag}\big(\theta(Wx)\big)\,V^T\big(V\sigma(Wx)-y\big)x^T \\\\
}$$

---

In the above, a colon is used to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= {\rm Tr}(A^TB) \\
}$$
which happens to commute with itself and with the Hadamard product
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= B:A \\
A:(B\odot C) &= (A\odot B):C \\
}$$
The product rule for differentials
$$\eqalign{
d(A\star B) = dA\star B + A\star dB \\
}$$
is quite general since $(\star)$ can denote any product (Kronecker, Frobenius, Hadamard, Dyadic, Tensor, etc) and $(A,B)$ can be any two matrices (or scalars, vectors, tensors) whose dimensions are compatible with the underlying product.

If a product is commutative then this rule is analogous to the one for scalars, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
d\big(A\star A\big)
 \;=\; \big(dA\star A + A\star dA\big)
 \;=\; 2A\star dA \\
}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! In trying to process your answer, we have the follow-up questions below: (1) Why $ds = h \odot dz$? (More specifically, where the Hadamard product came from? Is there any source you can refer us to?). (2) How should we apply the chain-rule when it comes to matrices? (for example, in consecutive steps that starts with the step $dL = p:dp$)

Comment: (3) When and why do you use $\partial$ or $d$? What's the difference?

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your 2nd question. For the 3rd question, $d$ denotes the _differential_ while the partial derivative notation $\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X}$ indicates that every element in the numerator may depend upon any (or every) element of the denominator. As for the 1st question, perhaps index notation is best  
$$ds_k=h_k\,dz_k$$
This is the component-wise version of the scalar result; expressing it in vector form requires the Hadamard product.

Comment: Can we generalize your answer for matrices? Specifically, to the settings below.
$$
L := \frac  1 2 \| V \sigma \left( WX \right) - Y \|_F^2
$$
and $
X \in \mathbb{R}^{(d \times n)}, 
W \in \mathbb{R}^{(k \times d)},
V \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times k)},
Y \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times n)}
$, for $\sigma \left( u \right) := \max \left( 0, u \right)$ element-wise.

Comment: Please correct us if we are wrong. Using your answer for the case of $x,y$ vectors, in a generalized case of $X, Y$ matrices and the Frobenius norm, the derivative is as follows.
$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial W} = \begin{bmatrix}
\sigma'((WX)_{1, 1}) & \sigma'((WX)_{1, 2}) & \cdots & \sigma'((WX)_{1, n}) \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
\sigma'((WX)_{k, 1}) & \sigma'((WX)_{k, 2}) & \cdots & \sigma'((WX)_{k, n})
\end{bmatrix} V^T (V \sigma (WX) - Y) X^T
$$

Comment: My calculation of the matrix case yields
$$
\frac{\partial L}{\partial W}
 = \Big(\sigma'(WX)\odot\big(V^TV\sigma(WX)-V^TY\big)\Big)X^T
$$

Comment: Greg, thank you very much for your reply!
Our result is different from yours. I'm afraid that it is because we misunderstood how to define and derivative the Hadamard product.
Could you please explain your steps that led to the difference in the results?