# The Scalar-to-Matrix Derivative of $\frac 1 2 \| V \sigma \left( Wx \right) - Y \|_F^2$ w.r.t. $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I'd appreciate your help in confirming the following calculation  (or pointing out the bugs) of [$\frac {\partial L} {\partial V}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix), where

$$
L := \frac  1 2 \| V \sigma \left( WX \right) - Y \|_F^2
$$

and $
X \in \mathbb{R}^{(d \times n)}, 
W \in \mathbb{R}^{(k \times d)},
V \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times k)},
Y \in \mathbb{R}^{(m \times n)}
$, for $\sigma \left( u \right) := \max \left( 0, u \right)$ element-wise.

---

I've tried to follow the answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061629/the-scalar-to-matrix-derivative-of-frac-1-2-v-sigma-left-wx-right-y) post, and ended up having the expression below.

$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial V} = \big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big) \sigma(X^T W^T)
$$

Please confirm that it is mathematically true.

---

Tnx.

Comment: The order needs to be reversed $\;\Big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \Big)\;\sigma\big(X^T W^T\big)\;$

Comment: I've updated the post according to your comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Does it mean that the partial derivative with respect to $V$'s $i$-th column, denoted as $v_i$, is the following?
$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial v_i} = \big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big) \sigma(X^T (W^T)_i),
$$
where $(W^T)_i$ denotes $(W^T)$'s $i$-th column.

Comment: BTW, we're currently focusing on a case where $\sigma(WX)$ is strictly positive for any entry. Therefore, in our case, it holds that $\sigma(WX) = WX$. If anyone has an answer only for this specific case, it could help us too (although a general answer is preferable, of course).

Comment: A fix according to Wiki's scalar-to-vector derivative convention:
$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial v_i} = \big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big)_i \sigma(X^T W^T),
$$
where $\big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big)_i$ is $\big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big)$'s $i$-th ***row***.

Comment: I'm more inclined to follow your original (non-Wikipedia) formula.

Comment: Just to confirm. Do you mean that the following is mathematically true?
$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial v_i} = \big( V \sigma(WX)-Y \big) \sigma(X^T (W^T)_i).
$$