# The Scalar-to-Matrix Derivative of $\frac 1 2 \| \vec{1}^T \sigma \left( W X \right) - \sigma \left( e_1^T X \right) \|_F^2$ w.r.t $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

I'd appreciate your help in confirming (or pointing out the bugs) the following calculation of [$\frac {\partial L} {\partial W}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus#Scalar-by-matrix).

---

Let

$$
L := \frac 1 2 \| \vec{1}^T \sigma \left( W X \right) - \sigma \left( e_1^T X \right) \|_F^2,
$$

where $
X \in \mathbb{R}^{(d \times n)}, 
W \in \mathbb{R}^{(d \times d)},
\vec{1} \in \mathbb{R}^{d}
$, $e_1$ is the first column of the identity matrix $I_d$, and $\sigma$ is the element-wise ReLU (that is, $\sigma \left( s \right)_i = \max \left( 0, s_i \right)$ for a vector $s$, and $\sigma \left( S \right)_{ij} = \max \left( 0, S_{ij} \right)$ for a matrix $S$).

I've tried to follow the answer in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4061629/the-scalar-to-matrix-derivative-of-frac-1-2-v-sigma-left-wx-right-y) post and ended up having the expression below.

$$
\frac {\partial L} {\partial W} = \left\{ \sigma' \left( WX \right) \odot \vec{1} \left[ \vec{1}^T \sigma \left( W X \right) - \sigma \left( e_1^T X \right) \right] \right\} X^T
$$

Please confirm that it is mathematically true.

---

Tnx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}\def\p{\partial}
\def\E{{\cal E}}
\def\L{\left}\def\R{\right}\def\LR#1{\L(#1\R)}
\def\vec#1{\operatorname{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\s#1{\sigma\LR{#1}}
\def\t#1{\theta\LR{#1}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
$As in the linked post, let $\,\t{z}\,$ denote the Heaviside step function and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
H &= \t{WX},\qquad S = \s{WX},\qquad dS = H\odot\LR{dW\,X} \\
b^T &= \s{e_1^TX},\qquad a^T = \o^TS-b^T \\
}$$
Then
$$\eqalign{
L &= \frac 12\LR{a^T:a^T} \\
dL &= a^T:da^T \\
 &= a^T:\o^TdS \\
 &= \o a^T:H\odot\LR{dW\,X} \\
 &= H\odot{\o a^T}:\LR{dW\,X} \\
 &= \LR{H\odot \o a^T}X^T:{dW} \\
\grad{L}{W}
 &= \LR{H\odot \o a^T}X^T \\
}$$
which matches your result.